# Is the amount of RAM used in dot-net projects more than other projects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ram

Is the amount of **RAM** used in **.net-Core** projects more than other projects

Comment: Why should it? What do you mean by "other projects"?

Comment: All Projects based on .netFrameWork

Comment: It is, and it is not. A pretty pointless question, unless you give more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your "other projects" its different.
 But based on msdn docs u have to use . net core instead of .net framework when:
 1. You have cross-platform needs.
 2. You are targeting microservices.
 3. You are using Docker containers.
 4. ((You need high-performance and scalable systems.))
 5. You need side-by-side .NET versions per application.

So .net core uses less resourcers comparing with .net framwork

Comment: Please send the msdn link , Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server bia dadash